# Do tert-butylcyclohexanes with a leaving group locked in the equatorial position undergo E1?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics

**Background**

Elimination of 1-bromo-*tert*-butylcyclohexane is a prototypical example of how important the anti periplanar relationship is for E2. From [Organic Chemistry: Structure, Mechanism, Synthesis
By J. David Rawn, Robert J. Ouellette [1, p. 281]](https://books.google.com/books?id=lScsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA281),

> The effect of conformation on E2 reactions is demonstrated by the difference in rates of the dehydrobromination of *cis*- and *trans*-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane. The axial bromine atom of the *cis* isomer is eliminated about 500 times faster than the equatorial atom of the *trans* isomer.[image: Elimination of 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane] Figure 9.8 shows that the axial bromine atom of the *cis* isomer is anti periplanar with respect to the axial hydrogen atoms at C-2 and C-6. Therefore, the most favorable geometry for elimination is "built into" the molecule, and no conformational equilibria are required to achieve it. In the *trans* isomer, however, no hydrogen atoms are anti periplanar to the equatorial bromine atom. To eliminate HBr in the *trans* isomer, a hydrogen atom that lies at a 60° dihedral angle with respect to the bromine atom must be removed. This process or any other reaction of a distorted ring that moves the two atoms into a better geometry for elimination requires more energy. Hence, the reaction rate is slower.[image: Figure 9.8]

The *tert*-butyl group is very bulky, resulting in strong 1,3-diaxial interactions when in the axial position. This makes the A value of the *tert*-butyl group exceptionally high—about 5 kcal/mol. Compare this with the [A values of other groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_value#Table_of_A-Values), almost all of which lie under 2 kcal/mol. This effect is so prominent that it results in conformation "locking" in *tert*-butylcyclohexanes, where the ring is forced to almost entirely take on the conformation with the *tert*-butyl group in the equatorial position. Quantitatively, there is a ratio of about [10,000 to 1](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2014/07/01/substituted-cyclohexanes-a-values/) equatorial conformers to axial conformers for *tert*-butylcyclohexane. In fact, sufficiently nucleophilic bases will prefer to react with *trans*-1-chloro-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane [via substitution rather than elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformational_isomerism#Conformation-dependent_reactions) even though nucleophiles prefer to substitute axial leaving groups.

The effect of the *tert*-butyl group on E2 is quite clear. Since it locks the bromine in the equatorial position in *trans*-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane, E2 is significantly harder to carry out. However, this conformational locking shouldn't have much of an effect on E1 as in that case an anti periplanar relationship between the leaving group and the abstracted hydrogen is not required. Other factors seem to be in favor of E1 in the elimination of *trans*-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane. Bromine is a good leaving group, and the resulting carbocation would be secondary. Of course, whether E1 or E2 occurs also depends on our solvent and base. I'm particularly interested in the reaction conditions from the excerpt above, KOtBu/HOtBu.

Strangely enough, I've found information on this quite scarce. Almost every instance I've seen the elimination of *trans*-1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane come up has been in the context of assessing which isomer of 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane will undergo E2/elimination faster. There seems to be little information on the actual rate law of the elimination.

I've managed to find a few places where it's said that 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane or similar molecules with different leaving groups will undergo E1 elimination. Slide 37 of [this presentation](https://nptel.ac.in/content/storage2/courses/104101005/downloads/LectureNotes/chapter%207.pdf) says that *trans*-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexyl tosylate undergoes E1/SN1 with NaOEt/EtOH:
[image: Elimination of 4-*tert*-butylcyclohexyltosylate]
Unfortunately, there don't seem to be any references, but the exact same thing is said in [Organic Chemistry, Part 2 of 3 by Richard Daley [p. 582]](https://books.google.com/books?id=8MxEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA582):

> The difference in elimination pathways between *cis*- and *trans*-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexyl tosylate illustrates the importance of molecular conformation. Because of its size, the *tert*-butyl group actively locks the cyclohexane ring with the *tert*-butyl group in the equatorial position. In the *cis*isomer, the smaller tosylate group is in the axial position; and in the *trans* isomer, it is in the equatorial position.
>
> Both compounds react with ethoxide ion in ethanol to eliminate the tosyl group and a β hydrogen to form 4-*tert*-butylcyclohexene. However, the reaction of the *cis* isomer follows E2 kinetics, whereas the reaction of the *trans* isomer follows E1 kinetics. The *cis* isomer has the tosyl group and the β hydrogen in an anti-coplanar conformation; thus, allowing the base to easily remove the β hydrogen.
>
> Because of the size of the *tert*-butyl group, the *trans* isomer does not easily get into either the anti- or syn-coplanar conformation. Thus, the rate of the reaction is quite slow.

Again, there weren't any references to papers confirming this. Aside from these two places, I could not find anything else claiming that *trans*-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexyl tosylate undergoes E1 elimination. On the contrary, I did find [a paper](https://doi.org/10.1002/cber.19861190107) that suggests *trans*-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexyl tosylate undergoes E2 rather than E1 elimination in HFIP:

> Reactions of the epimeric 4‐*tert*‐butylcyclohexyl tosylates in hexafluoroisopropyl alcohol (HFIP) (1e, 1a ) allow for the first time to observe SN1‐type non‐stereospecific substitution, whereas conventional solvents including even trifluoroethanol yield SN2‐type inversion by solvent assisted pathway (≙k <sub>s</sub>). Large differences are found between the epimers in the solvent participation, measured kinetically by the Schleyer‐Bentley equation. This, as well as the even enhanced elimination with the equatorial isomer 1e as compared to 1a (98% vs. 96% in HFIP) points to the occurrence of non‐chair intermediates from 1e ‐derivatives, and to more E2‐ than E1‐type reactions.

The two places I was able to find claiming that 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane undergoes E1 were pdfs of tests/exercises, presumably from undergraduate organic chemistry classes. [This one](https://sites.ualberta.ca/~eblackbu/chim161/new%20problems/Exercise%2013%20-%20Elimination%20reactions%20-%20answers.pdf) makes the claim in problem 4, and [this one](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Kyed4LEJ3_4J:homepage.westmont.edu/marten/organic/orga03/Problems14ans.pdf%20&cd=58&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) (original pdf link is dead so only cached view is available) makes the claim in problem 7. Searches for literature confirming or denying whether this claim is true proved mostly futile. I did find [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.joc.9b01428), which suggests an E2 mechanism for the elimination of 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane by NaDA (the sodium counterpart to LDA):

> The cis- and *trans*-4-tert-butylcyclohexyl bromides show a preference for the elimination of the cis isomer (k<sub>cis/ax</sub>/k<sub>trans/eq</sub> = 10). Rate and isotopic labeling studies are consistent with a trans-diaxial E2 elimination via trisolvated monomer for the cis isomer and a carbenoid mechanism via disolvated monomer for the trans isomer.

However, NaDA is significantly more basic than alkoxides (compare the pKa of diisoprpylamine, 36, to the typical pKa range of alcohols, 16-18), so the elimination may go via E2 in large part because the base is so strong.

**Question**

I am curious whether conformational locking by a *tert*-butyl group is strong enough to force molecules like 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane to undergo E1 elimination in conditions that otherwise favor E2, particularly in the case where the base/solvent is an alkoxide/alcohol like tBuOK/tBuOH. If so, to what extent can we see E1 creep its way into E2 territory as a result of this type of conformational locking? And in particular, is there some literature on this subject, especially for the case of 1-bromo-4-*tert*-butylcyclohexane?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to understand what you are asking, mostly because of your choice of words. "E1 creep ints way into E2 territory" You're making the E2 reaction so slow that other mechanisms (E1, specifically) are now fast, by comparison. We're not making E1 faster by itself, just in relation.

Comment: @Zhe sorry about that. Obviously what’s happening E2 is becoming slower by comparison, but I’m talking about elimination reactions that would otherwise favor E2 if the cyclohexane wasn’t conformationally locked now favoring E1.

Comment: You should check Reaxys or Scifinder Scholar. I'm sure that those examples are based on literature precedence.